# One layout over another at run time?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My game app has many complex graphical elements and I am worried that having a banner ad continuously on screen will detract too much from the game. My plan is that the user will be able to play each "level" in the game using the full screen without any ads, but upon completion of each level an ad will slide in, on top of the top part of the screen. Presumably this means I have to somehow create a layout programatically that will appear on top of the existing screen layout. Can this be done? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.
Afaik you simply have to create a layout which is android:backgroundcolor="transparent".
Else you could do it so you started a new activity on each level completion?